# Post image to facebook from image.php

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

In my index file, I display a randomized image from image.php file. I'm trying to find the way to get the image display in the index file to post to facebook wall.

Is there any way i can post an image generated from image.php to facebook wall?

```
//index file
<img src="image.php">

//post to wall file
$facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", array(
    'message' => "",
    'picture' => "",       //same image from image.php goes here
    'link' => "",
    'name' => "",
    'caption' => ""
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site is example.com, this should work just fine:

```
'message' => 'http://example.com/image.php',
```

Note: I'd recommend being consistent with your quotes - either always use single or double quotes, don't mix them like you did here.

### Update

Replace the image tag where you display the image with this:

```
//index file
<img src="image.php?postfb=1">
```

*image.php*:

```
// image selection/generation code first
// there's probably an URL to the image here somewhere, I'll assume its $image_url

// then:
if (isset ($_GET ['postfb'])) {
    //post to wall file
    $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", array(
        'message' => "",
        'picture' => $image_url, 
        'link' => "",
        'name' => "",
        'caption' => ""
    ));
}
```

Comment: The image generated from the image.php is a random image, which will display different image each time the page is refresh within index file. Will the image posted on facebook and display on the index file be the same?

Comment: Hmm no, but maybe you could add the Facebook post code to the end of image.php? There's really no way to get the same image with the code you're currently using

Comment: I think putting the Facebook post code to the end of image.php will not solve the problem because it will call image.php again. So it's possible that the image will be different. And puting the code at the end, will also considered Auto post. So which code you suggest?

Comment: Maybe you could add a parameter to the end of image.php, like image.php?postfb=true. Then in image.php you add the code, but with an if-statement to check for that parameter. That way, whenever the parameter is set to true, the same image will be posted as the one being displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Store image path in $img_path variable as like below

```
$img_path = file_get_contents('imgage.php');
```

if image.php show real path of image eg: http://www.example.com/image/sample.jpg. 
if not make it as real path.... else it fb wont accept the image...

Code to post on FB wall

```
 $attachment = array('message' => 'message'
           'name' => 'Sample',
           'picture' => $img_path);

 $result = $facebook->api('/'. $fb_id . '/feed/', 
                          'post',
                           $attachment);
```

Comment: $img_path = $img = file_get_contents('imgage.php'); instead of this line use $img_path = file_get_contents('image.php'); sorry for mistake

Comment: The image.php won't have real path because i random a picture then overlay it with a user profile picture. Saving the picture as real path is possible but this would create too many traffic and too many files created on the sever if i have large number of user. Any other alternative?

Comment: you can store real path in one variable and use as folows
$rpath = "www.example.com/image/";
$img_path = $rpath.$img_path;
This may help you....


Use this line before $attachment = array(...)